# passing 'this' as a parameter but operate in the context of the calling function

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parameter-passing, this

I'd like to be able to offload setStatus() to take a few arguments - but right now I can't even get the hardcoded selectors to work. How do i offload the setStatus() function correctly?

HTML

```
<div id="first:test"> <span class="statusFlag"></span>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Stuff">Box 1</input>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Stuff">Box 2</input>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Stuff">Box 3</input>
</div>
<div id="second:test"> <span class="statusFlag"></span>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Stuff">Box 1</input>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Stuff">Box 2</input>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Stuff">Box 3</input>
</div>
<div id="noTest">
  <input type="checkbox" value="stuff">No Validate</input>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('[id$=test] input:checkbox').change(function () {
  if ($(this).parent().children('input:checkbox').filter(':checked').length > 0) {
    setStatus(this);
  } else {
    $(this).closest('[id$=test]').find('.statusFlag').css('color', 'red').text('Incomplete');
  }
});

function setStatus(oldthis){
  alert(oldthis);
  $(oldthis).closest('[id$=test]').find('statusFlag').css('color', 'green').text('Complete');
}
```

The idea is to pass selectors dynamically and have text set for each div section...so eventually something like:

```
setStatus(this, '[id$=test]', 'red', 'Incomplete');
```

Fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/pMAXs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not finding a class in the second selector.

```
$(oldthis).closest('[id$=test]').find('statusFlag').css('color', 'green').text('Complete');
```

"statusFlag" -> ".statusFlag"

Assuming I understood your end goal to be correct, see: http://jsfiddle.net/pMAXs/3/

Comment: Ugh. It feels like Monday. Thanks for the help with another set of eyes.